# Object reference not set to an instance of an object ViewData["Title"] = "Index";

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

So I'm trying to create a register razor page in my index page using a modal. Most of the  form code that I imported into the modal is from the existing external register page. When I start up the mvc app, though, I receive a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Console:**

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in C:\Users\SalvadorSolis\source\repos\AWSCognitoMVC\AWSCognitoMVC\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 4
```

**HTML:**

```
@page
@model AWSCognitoMVC.Views.Home.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";//line 4
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
```

**Model:**

```
namespace AWSCognitoMVC.Views.Home
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<CognitoUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly CognitoUserManager<CognitoUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly CognitoUserPool _pool;

        public IndexModel(
            UserManager<CognitoUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<CognitoUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<IndexModel> logger,
            CognitoUserPool pool)
        {
        _userManager = userManager as CognitoUserManager<CognitoUser>;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _pool = pool;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 10)]
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        //Added because users don't usually add in a + in their phone number
        if (!(Input.PhoneNumber.First() == '+'))
        {
            Input.PhoneNumber = "+" + Input.PhoneNumber;
        }
        //Added because users don't usually add in a + in their phone number

        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = _pool.GetUser(Input.UserName);

            user.Attributes.Add(CognitoAttributesConstants.Email, Input.Email);
            user.Attributes.Add(CognitoAttributesConstants.PreferredUsername, Input.UserName);
            user.Attributes.Add(CognitoAttributesConstants.PhoneNumber, Input.PhoneNumber);

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                return RedirectToPage("./ConfirmAccount");
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
namespace AWSCognitoMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** The original Register Model did not have the "Title" defined and somehow worked fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Just use ViewBag instead if you are going to do it in razor view: `ViewBag.Title = "Index"`

Comment: Why the controller **and** the razor page? Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to mix controller & view approach with razor pages. Just **don't do it**. If you want to use razor pages create `Pages` folder in the root of the project and create your razor pages there. If you want to display razor page's view by `/home/index` url create `Home` folder in `Pages` folder and add your `IndexModel` there.

```
Pages\Home\Index.cshtml
```

Read more [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 1):

ViewData is a container to pass data from the PageModel to the content page.

So I guess it makes sense to set data on the PageModel side this way:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [ViewData]
    public string Title{ get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Title = "Index";
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then just get it this way:

```
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the same error on the same line still appears even with this code.

Comment: Something wrong with the project itself. Can you reproduce the error if you create a new project from scratch?

Comment: Yeah, I did that before posting and no luck.

Comment: @SalS Could you share us a demo which could reproduce your issue?