# Why is my HttpContext null on a Razor Page View Model?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm a newbie looking for some help.
I'm using netcoreapp2.2 for working in an already existing project and managed to put together a working
Model from multiple questions and tutorials like so:

```
public class AdminViewModel : PageModel
{
    public string Username
    {
        get => GetCookie("username");
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get => GetCookie("password");
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    private string GetCookie(string cookieName)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext;
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        string result;
        if (request.Cookies.TryGetValue(cookieName, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

With the View:

```
@model Regulator2App.Web.Views.Admin.AdminViewModel
@{
    string username = Model.Username;
    string password = Model.Password;
    bool isLoggedIn = username.Equals("admin") && password.Equals("admin");
}
@if (isLoggedIn)
{
    <div>"You're in!"</div>
}
else
{
    <button id="cookie">Create cookies</button>
}
<script src="~/js/admin.js"></script>
```

And the controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("/admin/")]
    public IActionResult AdminView()
    {
        return View(new AdminViewModel());
    }
}
```

My idea is adding a listener on the Create cookies button to add some cookies and then retrieve them via the model, the problem I'm facing is that my `context` is always null:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AdminViewModel.GetCookie(string cookieName) in AdminView.cshtml.cs
HttpRequest request = context.Request;
```

How can I properly access the context to retrieve the cookies?

Comment: As far as I am aware the HttpContext property should not be null. However, an alternative would be to inject an `IHttpContextAccessor`, I wouldn't suggest this until you have figured out the problem.

Comment: Agreed, it looks fine. Can you share the exact exception stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpContext` is `null` because you are creating `AdminViewModel` instance manually but it **should be created by the framework**. The problem is that you are mixing [razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) with [controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-3.1) while these are completely different things and should not be used together as I mentioned in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54817448/7775908).

Comment: Thank you! I'm using razor pages only and simplified the code to look like this: 
@{
    string username;
        Context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("username", out username);

}